# Store values in javascript object with same keys

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following code to extract values from a JSON response. What I am trying to do is store the data in a similar way to how you would with an associative array in php. Apologies for the code being inefficient. The array comments written down are how I would like it to look in the object.

```
$.each(responseData, function(k1,v1){
            if(k1 == "0"){
                $.each(v1, function(k2,v2){
                    $.each(v2, function(k3, v3){
                        if(k3 == "val"){
                          //store in object here
                          //Array1 = array("time"=>k2, "iVal"=>v3)
                          console.log(k3 + v3 + k2);
                        }else{
                           //Array2 = array("time"=>k2, "aVal"=>v3)
                           console.log(k3 + v3 + k2);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
});
```

So all the information is there but I am not sure how to store each instance for the values in an object. I did try store it like this:

```
//obj created outside

obj1.date = k2;
obj2.iVal = v3;
```

But doing this clearly overwrote every time, and only kept the last instance so I am wondering how can I do it so that all values will be stored?

Edit: Added input and output desired.

Input

```
{"0":{"18.00":{"iVal":85.27,"aVal":0.24},"19.00":{"iVal":85.27,"aVal":0.36},"20.00":{"iVal":0,"aVal":0}}, "success":true}
```

Desired output

```
array1 = {"time":"18.00", "iVal":85.27},{"time":"19.00", "iVal":85.27},{"time":"20.00", "iVal":0}
array2 = {"time":"18.00", "aVal":0.24},{"time":"19.00", "aVal":0.36},{"time":"20.00", "aVal":0}
```

Comment: Can you supply sample _input_ and desired output ? (instead of all this code) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Edited it please have a look. My indexing for the desired output could be incorrect as I am not too clear with javascript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var g1=[];
var g2=[];


for ( a in o[0])
  {
    g1.push({time:a , iVal:o[0][a]['iVal']})
    g2.push({time:a , aVal:o[0][a]['aVal']})

}
```

http://jsbin.com/qividoti/3/edit

[image]

Comment: I just tried a fiddle for this with my returned data and worked fine but when I try it in my application it gives an undefined result, when I returning encoded `JSON` data and using it as the object do I have to do anything different?

Comment: @user3144542 can u supply the json ?

Comment: The JSON when outputted to my log is exactly the same as the input above. Unless you mean something different?

Comment: I did use your json 1:1. so where is the problem ?

Comment: @user3144542 can you supply the ' it gives a `different result`'

Comment: From the look of it, it seems to take the `0` as the `a` value and that is why the subsequent data is undefined.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Im sure its a problem with my code but the answer is fine. I will fiddle around with my code to try fix it. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

a json response can be converted back to a js object literal by calling `JSON.parse(jsonString)` inside the success callback of your ajax call.

from then on there is no need for iterating over that object since you navigate it like any other js object which is can be done in two ways either

the js way -> dot notation

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStirng);
var value = obj.value;
```

or like a php array

```
var value = obj["value"];
```

Comment: I can't do that because the `value` will not be known and is dynamically please see the edit which may clear things up.

Comment: the `value` is a placeholder for whatever 'value' you want to use ! in fact it is the key of the array or object which could also be called object.property